Python Protocols and Mutability
I'm confused by a Pylance type-checking error I'm getting:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import StrEnum
from typing import Protocol

class A(Protocol):
    x: str
    # @property
    # def x(self)->str: ...

class S(StrEnum):
    FOO="foo"
    BAR="bar"

@dataclass
class AA:
    x: S


def f(a: A): return

a = AA(S.BAR)

f(a) # type-checking error

Via VS Code, Pylance tells me:
Argument of type "AA" cannot be assigned to parameter "a" of type "A" in function "f"
  "AA" is incompatible with protocol "A"
    "x" is invariant because it is mutable
    "x" is an incompatible type
      "S" is incompatible with "str"

I don't understand Pylance's complaint. Isn't every version of x here mutable? The error can be fixed if we make A.x immutable by replacing the declaration x: str with the @property-decorated method commented out in the above code snippet. This actually increases my confusion -- in this case, instances of AA shouldn't conform to A since A.x is immutable but AA.x isn't, right?

When x can be both read and written to, its type is invariant (this is also the case with, for instance, list[str] and SomeSubclassOfList[S]; the latter is not a subtype of the former). By declaring x a read-only attribute with @property, you ensure that things expecting an A (like f) can only ever read (and not write to) its x; that the actual attribute (AA.x) can be written to simply doesn't matter when it is not used at all. These questions are very common; I'll look for duplicates.
